# Don't show addresses of customers in admin panel

Tags: magento2, customer, adminhtml, magento2.2.3, customer-address

Magento version: 2.2.3 Enterprise Edition.

When I go to customer tab in admin panel and to address tab the addresses should not render(as I have more than 50 addresses for some customers. So the customer page in admin panel hangs).[image]

So need to know which file renders the addresses so that I can add plugin to that, not to render the addresses.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `customer_form.xml` at following location

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml

and add the following piece of code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="address">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```